# Angular 2/4 - Can't resolve all parameters for GameEditComponent: ([object Object], [object Object], ?)

Tags: json, angular, rest, service

I am developing the services of my application, but when I try to load the page it shows the following error:

> Can't resolve all parameters for GameEditComponent: ([object Object],
>   [object Object], ?).

I tried in the service to put as an array or just leave any, but even then the error continued

game-edit.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class GameEditService {

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getGame(id): Observable<any> {

        return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/lightning/api/game' + id).map(res => res.json()).catch(error => {

            throw new Error(error.message);

        });

    }

    getManufactures(): Observable<any> {

        return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/lightning/api/manufacture').map(res => res.json()).catch(error => {

            throw new Error(error.message);

        });

    }

    getPlatforms(): Observable<any> {

        return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/lightning/api/platform').map(res => res.json()).catch(error => {

            throw new Error(error.message);

        });

    }

}
```

game-edit.component.ts

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { GameEditService } from './game-edit.service';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'app-game-edit',
    templateUrl: './game-edit.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./game-edit.component.css', '../styles.css' ]
})
export class GameEditComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private gameEditService: GameEditService, private id) {

        this.gameEditService.getPlatforms().subscribe(platforms => {

            console.log(platforms);

        }), erro => console.log(erro);

        this.gameEditService.getManufactures().subscribe(manufactures => {

            console.log(manufactures);

        }), erro => console.log(erro);

    }

    ngOnInit() {

        this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {

            this.id = params['id'];

            console.log(this.id);

        });

        this.gameEditService.getGame(this.id).subscribe(game => {

            console.log(game);

        }), erro => console.log(erro);

    }

    onSubmit(form){

        console.log(form);

    }

    verificaValidTouched(campo){

        return !campo.valid && campo.touched;

    }

    aplicaCssErro(campo){

        return {

            'subError': this.verificaValidTouched(campo)

        }

    }

}
```

This is the json that is coming, the first is for a selected game, the second is for the platforms and the third is for the manufacturers

json game selected

```
{
    "id":1,
    "name":"Street Fighter",  
    "category":"luta",
    "price":20.5,
    "quantity":1000,
    "production":true,
    "description":"descricao",
    "image":"ps4.jpg",
    "manufacture":
    {
       "id":1,
       "name":"Sony",
       "image":"ps4.jpg",
       "imageFullPath":"http://localhost:8080/lightning/images/ps4.jpg"
    }
}
```

json platforms

```
{
    "id":1,
    "name":"PC",
    "image":"ps4.jpg",
    "imageFullPath":"http://localhost:8080/lightning/images/ps4.jpg"
}
```

json manufactures

```
{
    "id":1,
    "name":"Sony",
    "image":"ps4.jpg",
    "imageFullPath":"http://localhost:8080/lightning/images/ps4.jpg"
}
```

[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsNon.png)

I'm using angular cli with with all packages in the most current versions.
I do not know if maybe this error is because of the platforms you have inside the game, or some other code problem, if you know something that could do to repair, I tried several solutions that I found through the internet, but none worked.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why does the component take an id in it's constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the last argument in the component's constructor, `private id`. Angular will try to resolve this dependency, but can't find an injectable class for `id`. When looking at the code, I think there is no need to inject `id` into the constructor. Just define it as a property on your component:

```
// ... import statements

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'app-game-edit',
    templateUrl: './game-edit.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./game-edit.component.css', '../styles.css' ]
})
export class GameEditComponent implements OnInit {

    private id; // put the declaration of id here

    // remove id declaration from the constructor, no need to inject it
    constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, 
                private gameEditService: GameEditService) { // ...constructor code}

    // other code
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it otherwise: My problem was that the `HttpClient` has a rare condition, it's not the same "import" line on the component that on the app.module...

On the Component is this:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

in app module is this:

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
```